# Asp.Net Core 2.0 Linux Arm - SQLIte issue

Tags: asp.net, linux, sqlite, asp.net-core, raspberry-pi

we are currently trying to run asp.net core 2.0 (latest preview) on Linux arm (Raspberry Pi - Ubuntu Mate) and we were able to solve almost all the issues so application works very well.

Not we are trying to run it with SQL Db (Sqlite) and on Windows, everything works fine, we can connect and read the DB but on the linux, we are getting following error:
System.DllNotfoundException: Unable to load DLL 'e_sqlite3': The specified module or one of its dependencies could not be found. (Exception from HRESULT: 0x8007007E).

I think I already tried everything, installed sqlite on linux, but nothing helped.

Any idea what might be wrong?

Thanks a lot
Rado

Answer (score 1):

i changed the library that I used to connect to sqlite to this one
https://www.nuget.org/packages/sqlite-net-pcl/

and then (and not sure why), on linux, i had to take their implementation of SQLite.cs and manually add it to the project.
So for Linux, i had to have that CS included and for windows, i just excluded it so the one which was part of DLL works. Didn't do more investigation, but it works on Windows and Linux as well.
If you need more help just let me know.

https://github.com/oysteinkrog/SQLite.Net-PCL

This file:
https://github.com/praeclarum/sqlite-net/blob/master/src/SQLite.cs

Thanks
Rado

Answer (score 1):

I think we'll have to wait, the [issue](https://github.com/ericsink/SQLitePCL.raw/issues/161) isn't closed.

**UPDATE:**

this issue is closed and launched new version. You only need install the last version 1.1.8 of the package SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green and SQLite in ARM works fine.

Answer (score 0):

I am having the same issue and I after some investigation I think this happens because e_sqlite3.dll for ARM is not (yet) included the `SQLitePCLRaw.bundle_green` package.

This package contains the dll for different architectures but `linux-arm` is not yet mentioned in the dependencies (`linux, osx and v110xp (win7)` are).

We probably have to wait until the .NET Core ARM team adds it properly...